# Splitting Method

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Consider the iteration matrix for the general splitting method $M=I-N^{-1}A$ where $N$ is any invertible matrix.  Show that if $\lambda =1$ is an eigenvalue of $M$. then $A$ cannot be invertible.

I tried: $$1) Mx = \lambda x$$ $$2) (I-N^{-1}A)x = x$$ $$3) x-N^{-1}Ax = x$$ $$4) 0 = N^{-1}Ax$$ $$5) 0 = Ax$$
But i'm not sure how this help show invertibility of A.

Comment: You made a strange leap in the 3rd equation above.

Comment: From which steps?

Comment: I don't know, you wrote them. How did you go from 2) to 3)? You only know that 2) holds for $v$, not the entire space.

Comment: Ah! I see now I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Mv = v$ for some $v \neq 0$ then $v - N^{-1} A v = v$ and so $N^{-1} A v = 0$. Multiplying by $N$
gives $A v = 0$, hence $A$ is not invertible.